# Remove link in image inside <a> tag

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

If I insert an image inside an `<a>` tag, how could I avoid, using js if it was necessary, that when someone clicks on that image it doesn't follow the link.

Comment: Why insert the image inside an anchor tag if you don't want the link to be followed? Maybe you could mark up the image using an alternative approach, rather than overriding the default behaviour of the anchor tag?

Comment: I'm adding images to web pages that are already written, and sometimes they are inside anchor tags. I can't avoid this situation to happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to handle the `<img>`'s `click` event and `return false;`.

For example:

```
<img src="..." href="..." onclick="return false;" />
```

Or, using [jQuery](http://jquery.com):

```
$('a.SomeClass img').click(function() { return false; });
```

However, the best solution is to move the `<img>` outside the `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to other answers on this page: you should style an anchor tag with a background image using css instead of using an image tag eg

```
{background: transparent url('images/myimage.png') width:20px height:20px}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also do it by event handling:

```
$('a.SomeClass img').click(function(event) { 
   event.preventDefault(); 
   return false;
 });
```

the 'event' object is automatically passed in the 'click' event handler in jQuery. Note that preventDefault() is a native javascript call on the event object, so it can be used w/o jQuery as well.